# How to handle webhook in octobercms?

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, octobercms

I am developing a webapp with payment feature on it and I need to integrate webhook to get updates from the payment gateway similar to stripe when payments are made and use it to do stuff like send emails etc., and also grant excess to certain features when a subscription is made.

I am using ngrok to generate a temporary public facing url. I already created a route.php file in my plugin directory and have this in it

```
<?php

Route::any('/webhook/rave', 'Corymillz\Adverts\Http\Controllers\Webhook@index');

?>
```

In my plugin directory I also created a folder Http and in it I created another folder Controllers and in it I created a php file Webhook.php. In the file I have this is test it out

```
<?php namespace Corymillz\Adverts\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Request;
use Log;

class Webhook extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info('hello');
    }
}

?>
```

I have already added my webhook url `example.ngrok.io/webhook/rave` to the payment gateway webhook page
but nothing seem to be happening when I try test payment. I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I have yet to use stripe and only dabbled into webhooks a few times but I know that Authorize.net, Quickbooks, Avalara, Stamps.com, Google api(s), and Endicia all return post information when you use their calls. So for example when I send a payment to Authorize.net if it returns with a successful transaction id I send a receipt to customer. If it is declined I return information to the customer that their info was declined.

Comment: My question is not specific to stripe. Did u implement it using octobercms?  Just want to know how to handle the request sent to the route. If it is coming in i should see some update in my ngrok running cmd at least when i try a test payment. @PettisBrandon

Comment: Yes I implemented all of those with OctoberCMS in a plugin I made. I was trying to say, I haven't had the need to use a webhook (unless post information is a webhook).